# Rename only one file in each directory, based on condition

Tags: bash, files, rename, test

I have 100 folders inside every folder I have one or two files named as the following:

```
XXX_001_014_max.jpg
XXX_001_024_max.jpg
```

I saved the folders names in a file "list.txt"

I ran the following code to rename the files inside the folders at once:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat list.txt); do
mv ${i}/XXX_001_014_max.jpg ${i}/image.jpg
done
```

I aim to rename only the file `XXX_001_014_max.jpg` to `image.jpg`
and if this file does not exist(i.e. I have only one file inside the folder), then I want the code to rename the second file `XXX_001_024_max.jpg` to `image.jpg`

I know how to rename the files using the command `mv` but I am not familiar with the exact usage of `if` statement in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the `for i in $(cat squeeze)` construct - it will fail if any of your directory names contains *IFS* characters...
I would read the lines into an array and then simply rename the first file in each directory. Since you *always have one or two files* in each directory, that means renaming the first one in each directory should do the job - e.g. with `bash`:

```
mapfile -t mylist <list.txt
for i in "${mylist[@]}"
do
set -- "$i"/*
echo mv -- "$1" "$i"/image.jpg
done
set --
```

Remove the `echo` if you're happy with the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ -f XXX_001_014_max.jpg ]
then
  SOURCE=XXX_001_014_max.jpg
else
  SOURCE=XXX_001_024_max.jpg
fi
mv $SOURCE image.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ -f XXX_001_014_max.jpg ] 
then
    mv XXX_001_014_max.jpg image.jpg
else 
    mv XXX_001_024_max.jpg image.jpg
fi
```